# How to add search engines like _addOrganic in new analytics.js API?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics.js

for my new site I am using new analytics.js (as suggested by Google instead of ga.js). Works fine, except I don't see any keywords set in Google Analytics used in Google search by my visitors.

Seems strange to me as I would expect, that Google Analytics would recognize it's own search engine by default.

So I have tried to search for a way how to add new organic search in JS on my site as it was possible with ga.js [_addOrganic](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiSearchEngines#_gat.GA_Tracker_._addOrganic) function. But I have found nothing, there is no mention about this possibility for new analytics.js.

Can anybody give me some hints ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is no longer set in the code but via the admin interface. Go to ->admin->tracking info->organic search sources (see screenshot).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that. But any hints why Google search keywords are not set by default ?

Comment: Maybe all your visitors use encrypted connections (happens automatically if they search while they are logged in to Google) in which case the keyword is not send (will show up as "not set" in the reports). Organic search reports for Google searches are b now pretty much useless.